# Check if an array of objects includes object that has multiple values same as an object from other array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object `list.data`, that has multiple objects (around 2600). I have other array of objects `docs`. I need to check if any objects from `docs` array have multiple same values as any object from `list.data` array and remove those objects from `docs` array. The properties that I need to check are `name, reactionName, quizmaster, file and fileReaction`. I have put one object that should be removed to `docs` array. So far I have tried this code, but it doesnt seem to remove objects. It should remove every object from `docs` array that

1. has `name` and `reactionName` same as `name` of any object in `list.data` array, and
2. `quizmaster` same as `quizmaster` of any object in `list.data`, and
3. `file` and `fileReaction` same as `file` of any object in list.data.

```js
let docs = [{ name: "doc1", reactionName:"reactionName1", quizmaster: "qm1", file: "someFile1", fileReaction: "reactionFile1" },{ name: "doc2", reactionName:"reactionName2", quizmaster: "qm2", file: "someFile2", fileReaction: "reactionFile2" }]
let list = [{ name: "doc1", quizmaster: "qm1", file: "someFile1" },{ name: "doc2", quizmaster: "qm2", file: "someFile2" },{ name: "reactionName1", quizmaster: "qm1", file: "someFile1" }]

const noDuplicates = docs.filter(doc =>
    !list.some(el => doc.name == el.name)
    && !list.some(el => doc.reactionName == el.name)
    && !list.some(el => doc.file == el.file)
    && !list.some(el => doc.fileReaction == el.file)
    && !list.some(el => doc.quizmaster == el.quizmaster)
);

console.log(noDuplicates)

// expected result is docs = [{ name: "doc2", reactionName:"reactionName2", quizmaster: "qm2", file: "someFile2", fileReaction: "reactionFile2" }]
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? If there is something unclear, just ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please include [mcve] (and desired output)

Comment: @appleapple I think i did include desired output.
"It should remove every object from docs array that has name and reactionName same as name of any object in list.data array & quizmaster same as quizmaster of any object in list.data & file and fileReaction same as file of any object in list.data."

Comment: [mcve] means we can **click and run**. one important part is it's just code, so everyone can clearly see what's going on.

Comment: you can [edit] the snippet to make it **run without error** and complete the expected result

Comment: revert the edit as it's purpose is only for demonstrate snippet and mcve

Comment: @appleapple added some sort of snippet, hope it helps

Comment: `doc2` is **exact match** of `list[1]`, why you think it'd not be removed?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to brute force but a if you are concerned about speed, you are looking for a [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which is related to concepts around indexing your data.

Something like this

```
const constructHash = obj => `${obj['name']}_${obj['reactionName']}_${obj['quizmaster']}_${obj['file']}_${obj['fileReaction']}`

const index = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(list.data)
.map(k => [constructHash(list.data), k]))

const cleanedData = docs.filter(doc => !index[constructHash(doc)])
```

Some notes

1. If any of those fields are large, this will slow down
2. Replace the delimiter (`_`) with whichever character you expect to see least often. It ends up not being that important in this specific case, but best practice is to have the delimiter be a character you never expect in the data.

Comment: This runs in linear time, whereas the brute force runs in exponential

Comment: This still returns the array with the object that shouldnt be there anymore. To be honest, I thought my code is going to work fine, since its just a condition. Really stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

replace `some` with `find` and it will work fine.
this worked for me:

```
const lista = {
    data: [
      { value: "abc", value2: "bcd" },
      { value: "defg", value2: "efgh" }
    ]
  };
  const listb = {
    data: [
      { value: "abc", value2: "bcd" },
      { value: "defg", value2: "jklm" }
    ]
  };

  const noDuplicates = lista.data.filter((doc) =>
    listb.data.find((el) => doc.value === el.value && doc.value2 === el.value2)
  );

  console.log(noDuplicates);
```

print out this:

```
(1) [Object]
 0: Object
    value: "abc"
    value2: "bcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

`(doc.name && doc.reactionName) === el.name` doesn't do what you think,

it first do `(doc.name && doc.reactionName)` which is either `true` or `false`, then it compare the value to `el.name`, obviously `boolean === string` would never be `true`

---

You can check them one by one

```js
let docs = [{
  name: "doc1",
  reactionName: "doc1diff",
  quizmaster: "qm1",
   }, {
  name: "doc2",
  reactionName: "reactionName2",
  quizmaster: "qm2",
}]
let list = [{
  name: "doc1",
}, {
  name: "doc3",
  quizmaster: "qm3",
  file: "someFile3"
}]

const noDuplicates = docs.filter(doc => 
  !list.some(el => doc.name == el.name)
  && !list.some(el => doc.reactionName == el.name)
  //&& !list.some(el => doc.xxx == el.xxx)
  //...
  //...
);

console.log(noDuplicates)

// expected result is docs = [{ name: "doc2", reactionName:"reactionName2", quizmaster: "qm2", file: "someFile2", fileReaction: "reactionFile2" }]
```

Comment: I am a little bit afraid of the || operator. The object should be removed only if  both name and reactionName props have the same value as el.name. Meaning that if reactionName is same as el.name, but name is different to el.name, the object shouldnt be removed. Same thing with file and reactionFile props. Will this solution work like that?

Comment: @AdamSulc in your example, doc1 doesn't have same `name` and `reactionName`, and it do be removed.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is my bad. Sorry I am sitting on this for like 8 hours. Gonna edit that.

Comment: @AdamSulc if `doc.name == el.name && doc.reactionName == el.name` then `doc.name == doc.reactionName` you can choose any two you like

Comment: @AdamSulc I also change `fileReaction` since I believe it's error on your example too

Comment: I dont know if I phrased it correctly. Basically I want to remove X objects from docs array if both doc.name and doc.reactionName values are included in any of the objects in list array.

Comment: While both doc.name and doc.reactionName can be different.

Comment: This removes the object if the condition is met, however it also removes objects that shouldnt be removed :(. I updated my question, hopefully its more clear now. Thank you for your time by the way

Comment: `doc2` is **exact match** of `list[1]`, why you think it'd not be removed?

Comment: Because no object in list has name: "reactionName2"

Comment: @AdamSulc but `list` doesn't contain `reactionFile1`, why doc1 removed?